# Print something remotely on paper

Tags: printing, remote-access

I need to print some kind of black-and-white receipts at an office. No human interaction should be required. Print jobs will come from my webserver.

I would love to have a printer available by a simple web-API.

Google-cloud-print comes to mind. But it's in Beta and I've been testing it with my own printer and it doens't work all the time.

I could have a small windows PC hooked up to a printer, but what kind of software does it need to run to listen for new printjobs and print them out?

How about some kind of Arduino-wifi-printer solution?

Comment: you might have better luck asking this question in the superuser site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Print has worked for me in the past.  Also, newer HP printers supporting ePrint can be [setup with an email address that you can send print jobs directly to](https://www.google.com/search?q=HP+ePrintCenter)

Comment: Thanks, I have actually taken another look at Google Cloud Printer, and with the right printer it works just fine!